# Simulate hover effect over tablets through chrome toggle device toolbar

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi I want to see hover effect over tablets. I have written the following code. It works on desktop, however, I don't see hover effect over tablet device through chrome toggle device toolbar,. I see the effect on click. Can't we see hover effect through toggle device toolbar ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
p:hover, p.hover_effect {
    color: red;
}
.hover {
-webkit-user-select: none;
-webkit-touch-callout: none;        
}
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<p class="hover">Some Text</p>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.hover').bind('touchstart touchend', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).toggleClass('hover_effect');
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't see any item with a class of `hover`.  what are you trying to 'hover' on?

Comment: Added that class to the lement, P             
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
p:hover, p.hover_effect {
    color: red;
}
.hover {
-webkit-user-select: none;
-webkit-touch-callout: none;        
}
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<p class='hover'>Some Text</p>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.hover').bind('touchstart touchend', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).toggleClass('hover_effect');
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: please edit your original answer.

Comment: I think there is no `hover` on touch devices, how could we hover on touch devices?!

Answer (score 0):

I just ran your code locally, and it seems to be working as expected.

If you apply make the `p`-tag have a class of `hover`, when not in Chrome Device mode, it works on hover, as expected.  Otherwise, in device mode, 'touching' (clicking) the item changes the colour successfully.

'Touch' is only initiated once the mouse has been clicked.

See the following gif for an example of what I mean.

[image]

Comment: Thanks David for reply. 

However, in Device mode, I want to see the effect (text color - red)  on hover without clicking.

Comment: @Sunny that's not a thing.  How would that work on an actual device?  You can't 'hover' on a tablet.  But your code is also listening on 'touchstart' and 'touchend'.  This means you'd *have* to press on it to get it to work.